# Looking for solution in Jena api on android

Tags: android, jena

Please Can any one used Jena API on Android code, i try to find a solution since six months,but no way.I used api sources in https://code.google.com/p/androjena/downloads/list ,it works for some **SPARQL** funcion,but there is a problem for others.For example, it's ok for Exemple1 but for Exemple2 there is a problem.

**Exemple1 :**

```
public void QueryEngine() {

    String sparqlQuery2 = "PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"+
                          "PREFIX  foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\n"+
                          "SELECT DISTINCT  ?Nom ?resource ?url\n"+
                          "WHERE\n"+
                          " { ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom .\n"+
                          " ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url\n"+
                          "?Nom <bif:contains> \"Apple\". \n"+
                          " FILTER langMatches(lang(?Nom), \"EN\")\n"+
                          "}";
    String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    Query qur = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery2);
    QueryEngineHTTP exec = new QueryEngineHTTP(service, qur);
    ResultSet results = exec.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.out(results);
}
```

**Exemple2 :**

```
public void QueryEngine() {

    String sparqlQuery2 = "PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"+
                          "PREFIX  foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>\n"+
                          "PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>\n"+
                          "SELECT DISTINCT  ?Nom ?resource ?url\n"+
                          "WHERE\n"+
                          " { ?resource rdfs:label ?Nom .\n"+
                          " ?resource foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url\n"+
                          " FILTER langMatches(lang(?Nom), \"EN\")\n"+
                          "?Nom <bif:contains> \"Apple\". \n"+
                          "Minus \n"+
                          "{ ?resource dbo:wikiPageRedirects|dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates ?dis} \n"+
                          "} ";

    String service = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql";
    Query qur = QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery2);
    QueryEngineHTTP exec = new QueryEngineHTTP(service, qur);
    ResultSet results = exec.execSelect();
    ResultSetFormatter.out(results);
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't know some functions like, FILTER NOT EXISTS, MINUS, BIND, and many othes. The code works well with the java APi jena, but with android, there is always problems.I even try this solution  http://elite.polito.it/index.php/research/downloads/182-jena-on-android-download, but I met other problems wih the recognition of some classes.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no `FILTER Minus` in SPARQL. `<bif:contains>` is a Virtuoso-specific extension.

Comment: sorry it was a typo, i mean MINUS, or FILTER NOT EXISTS... Indeed,there is a problem in ANDROJENA version, it is not a up to date and it doesn't support some functions.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it works.I am just changing:

`Query qur=QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery2);`

by

```
Query qur=QueryFactory.create(sparqlQuery2,Syntax.syntaxARQ);
```

and everything works fine.